# I got a Data Structure task and i was stuck in String Sorting function anyone help me out?

Tags: sorting

The idea of the project is to maintain the data of the dictionary in such a way that searching the word
becomes easy and efficient. Dictionary Dataset will be maintained in a text file. User will load the file
and create a linked list in such a way that all words with arranged in a sorted order just like a dictionary.
Nodes A,B,C to Z will be created while reading the file according to words. Suppose if there is no word
with letter F then node F will not be created
Here is and example [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b8bF.png)

Comment: And then what is your question?

Comment: i have to create a linked list function using two pointers next & down the next pointer maintain same characters like words with A & down pointer will maintain Alphabetical order A B C D.

Comment: you can sort strings with the help of the `strcmp(const char *, const char *)` function in the `string.h` library

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

1. read all words from text file
2. sort all words in alphabetical order
3. create list

I have defined the maximum length of a word as `5`, of course you have to adapt this to your needs. It depends on how the words are stored in the text file, for example if each line contains one word the length of the array is logically the number of lines in the text file.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define size_of_array 8



typedef struct word{
    char w[5];
    struct word* next;
} word;

typedef struct node{
    char c;//contains the character with which the words begin
    struct node* next;
    struct word* firstWord;
} node;


node *anchor = NULL; //points to first node of the list

node *getNodeByChar(char c){
    node *ptr = anchor;
    while(ptr != NULL && ptr->c != c){
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return ptr;
}

void addWordToNode(char c, char *w){
    word *newWord = (word *)malloc(sizeof(word));
    strcpy(newWord->w,w);
    newWord->next = NULL;
    node *n = getNodeByChar(c);
    word *wrd = n->firstWord;
    if(wrd == NULL){ //if newWord is the first word of the node
                     //set firstword to newWord
        n->firstWord = newWord;
    }else{
        //append newWord to wordlist of node
        while(wrd->next != NULL){
            wrd = wrd->next;
        }
        wrd->next = newWord;
    }
}

void addNode(char c){
    node *newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->c = c;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->firstWord = NULL;
    if(anchor == NULL){
        //newNode is first Node set anchor to newNode
        anchor = newNode;
    }else{
        //append node to list
        node *ptr = anchor;
        while(ptr->next != NULL){
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next = newNode;
    }
}

void createList(char array[][5]){
    char currentStartChar;
    currentStartChar = array[0][0];
    addNode(currentStartChar);//add first node
    for(int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++){
        if(array[i][0] != currentStartChar){//if beginning char changes add new Node
            currentStartChar = array[i][0];
            addNode(currentStartChar);
        }
        addWordToNode(currentStartChar,array[i]);//add word to Node
    }
}

void printList(){ //printing the list
    node *ptr = anchor;
    word *wPtr = NULL;
    while(ptr != NULL){//iterate through al nodes
        printf("%c: ",ptr->c);
        if(ptr->firstWord != NULL){
            wPtr = ptr->firstWord;
            while(wPtr != NULL){ //iterate through all words of node 'ptr'
                                 //with char 'ptr->c'
                printf("%s, ",wPtr->w);
                wPtr = wPtr->next;//next word
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        ptr = ptr->next;//next node
    }
}

 
//function to display array
void display(char array[][5]){
  for(int i=0; i<size_of_array; i++){
    printf("%s ", array[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
 
int main()
{
  //Words out of text file
  char array[size_of_array][5] = {
      "Ape",
      "Boy",
      "Ant",
      "Too",
      "Dog",
      "Dad",
      "Abc",
      "TTL"
  };

  //display the original array
  printf("Original array: ");
  display(array);

  char temp[5];

  //Sort array using the Bubble Sort algorithm
  for(int i=0; i<size_of_array; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<size_of_array-1-i; j++){
      if(strcmp(array[j], array[j+1]) > 0){
        //swap array[j] and array[j+1]
        strcpy(temp, array[j]);
        strcpy(array[j], array[j+1]);
        strcpy(array[j+1], temp);
      }
    }
  }

  //display the sorted array
  printf("Sorted Array: ");
  display(array);



  createList(array);

  printf("\n\n");
  printList();

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Original array: Ape Boy Ant Too Dog Dad Abc TTL 
Sorted Array: Abc Ant Ape Boy Dad Dog TTL Too


A: Abc, Ant, Ape,
B: Boy,
D: Dad, Dog,
T: TTL, Too,
```

Comment: Your work is great but i need pointers base single Linked list,

Comment: could you explain this further.

Comment: My solution shows what is described in the picture

Comment: I have to use Next pointer and Down Pointer to Maintain Linked list and While Insertion i have to sort string words and place them in there right place for this purpose use only pointers not arrays

Comment: But each element still have a wordlist?

Comment: @HunainAli for what do you need a down Pointer? Isn't a next pointer enough?

Comment: Nodes which contains same first letter will maintain next pointer

Comment: Nodes which contains different first letter will be maintain down pointer

Comment: Example : | this is down pointer

Ace->Asia->Axis
|
Ball->Bat->Bubble
|
Cat->Cast->Create
|
Dark->Down

Comment: @HunainAli So only the last element of each wordlist points to the first element of the next wordlist with the down pointer? With wordlist I mean all words with the same first letter.

Comment: See the question again to understand next & down pointer work

Comment: class Node
{ 
 public:  
 string data; 
 Node *next; 
 Node *down;
 Node()
 {
  next = NULL;
  down = NULL;
 } 
};